# Is there any non- scipy code out there that will create smooth interpolations of a 2d dataset?

Tags: python, charts, numpy, scipy, interpolation

**edit:** *A solution with with Numpy would be fine, I'd previously had problems installing both of them but I've got numpy on some systems now*

Something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline#Finite_difference would be great.

I have a set of x,y data points and I'm looking for a way to plot a smooth path between the datapoints.  I need to visit the actual points so Bezier curves won't cut it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: and why the non numpy code requirement?

Comment: I edited the post and removed the non-numpy constraint

Comment: So you want a 1D interpolation and not a 2D interpolation?

Comment: I think he wants 1d parametric interpolation

Comment: If you are trying to avoid installation issues, then I am not sure that avoiding the easily available and well supported scipy is a good idea. Other libraries which might provide such functionality are probably at least as hard to install but likely don't have as large of a user base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scipy polynomial interpolation module is reasonably stand-alone. You can copy the file into your own project, if you *really* need to avoid the dependency:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/interpolate/polyint.py

The same goes to the `splmake/spleval` pair of spline interpolation routines:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py

Answer (score 2):

for numeric computations in python, numpy is hard to avoid. You should try `scipy.interpolate`:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#spline-interpolation-in-1-d-procedural-interpolate-splxxx

And look for parametric spline. From the link:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
t = np.arange(0,1.1,.1)
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
y = np.cos(2*np.pi*t)
tck,u = interpolate.splprep([x,y],s=0)
unew = np.arange(0,1.01,0.01)
out = interpolate.splev(unew,tck)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y,'x',out[0],out[1],np.sin(2*np.pi*unew),np.cos(2*np.pi*unew),x,y,'b')
plt.legend(['Linear','Cubic Spline', 'True'])
plt.axis([-1.05,1.05,-1.05,1.05])
plt.title('Spline of parametrically-defined curve')
plt.show()
```

[image: result]